# How do I sell an unopened Macbook Pro?

Tags: hardware-recommendation

My old MBP broke, which Apple replaced for me. By the time they decided to replace it, I had bought another laptop.

I want to sell the unopened MBP that Apple gave me.

Is there anything I need to be aware of when selling the MBP to something?

For example, is it possible the MBP has been registered with my existing Apple ID, and that I have to unregister it? How do I check?

Also, when advertising the MBP, is it safe to tell potential buyers the serial number?

Comment: good luck checking it without opening it...

Comment: I'd never buy any device from a private seller without the serial number! What does it show at https://checkcoverage.apple.com/ for the serial number of that device. Also just because it's sealed, doesn't mean it's factory sealed, as shrink wrapping can easily be done at home. Additionally the device may not actually be new but refurbished.

Comment: Is it still shrink wrapped?  Do you have the original box?  Then the SN# will be on the box label.  You can check to see if that's associated with your AppleID

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would feel odd buying a laptop from a third-party that is still in the (purportedly) original shrink-wrap. I would take the MBP out of the box, power it up and see that it's fully functional, and then advertise it as "barely used" and "like new." And yes, you need to provide the serial number.

Comment: Fair point. I had planned to open the MBP with the buyer upon purchaser to check/demonstrate it working before receiving the money.

Also, good to know that providing the serial number is safe. I will do it. Thanks.